# Apache webserver : SSL certificate not understood

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to specify an SSL certificate to Apache webserver, but I am getting some strange errors. Unfortunately, I don't know that much about SSL. Can someone kindly help me out.

Error log in /var/log/apache2/error.log :

```
 [Mon Jan 11 16:32:23 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Jan 11 16:32:23 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Mon Jan 11 16:32:23 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Mon Jan 11 16:32:23 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Jan 11 16:32:23 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] Init: Private key not found
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Jan 11 16:34:18 2016] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
```

I have configured SSL in this way :

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
JkMount /* loadbalancer
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/domainname.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/domainname.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The files provided by SSL providers are `.ca-bundle, .p7c, .combined, .crt, .csr, .key, .key.pem.`

How can Apache then understand SSL. Kindly let me know. Thank you.

*Update*

As per Tim's suggestion, I did call `cat` on the files, they looked as follows :

cat file_name.crt :

```
---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---
Random Characters
---END CERTIFICATE--
```

cat file_name.key

```
 ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---
    Random Characters
    ---END CERTIFICATE--
```

cat file_name.key.pem

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: domain_name.com
    localKeyID: some integers here
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    Random Characters
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wrong tag` is the best indicator you have. Apache assumes that your keys and certificates look like this. Check the files you reference meet these criteria.

Certificate

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Key

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you are pointing to a file with additional metadata like this you will get the above error.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            xx:yy:zz...
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    ................
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Hi, I checked the .crt file with keytool -printcert -v -files filname.crt . Is that the correct way, if yes, then I don't see the certificate in the way you specified.

Comment: @weareborg you want to just cat the files

Comment: The `/path/to/domainname.crt` and `/path/to/domainname.key` files should be inspected to ensure they only contain the certificate and key respectively. Use your favourite editor of `cat` them in your terminal.

Comment: @HBruijn : It starts and ends properly as Tim had indicated. Like this --Start certificate-- random_characters --End Certificate-- . All in Block letters. Just one thing I noticed, even if I cat the key, it says Begin Certificate, instead of Begin Key. Is that normal?

Comment: I have added what I see in the certificate in the main post. Kindly have a look.. :-)

Comment: No, the key should start `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and then a block of random characters. You probably accidentally selected the wrong file to use as the key. You can inspect a certificate file with `openssl x509 -in file-with-cert. -noout -text`

Comment: @HBruijn : I duplicated the .key.pem file and edited it, removed the extra stuff, and then pointed that one. Now it works. :-)